# Authenticate user without Leaving Page

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication

I want to have a user auto login on one of my webapps. I am trying to use the method FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage without the redirect. I just want to log the use in and stay on the page. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you're using MVC you could use jQuery to call an action via $.ajax request to the server which could be used to authenticate a user and then issue a call back.

Comment: But why can't you just redirect the user to the same page, then? If you are already logging in the user and setting the authentication cookie this should work just fine, should it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method SetAuthCookie to add the authentication cookie to the cookies collection.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
```

This will create the cookie to authenticated the user for the following requests without redirecting the user.

Hope this helps.